# Delete a specific XML Element

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I'd like to delete a whole "TableData" Elemt with a specific ID (ID 10 in this case) from my xml:

```xml
<DataPaths>
  <TableData>
    <ID>10</ID>
    <TablePath>C:\Users\Tom\Test.xls</TablePath>
    <TableName>TestName</TableName>
    <Mode>TestMode</Mode>
  </TableData>
</DataPaths>
```

I tried two different solutions and I think I'm almost there.

Solution 1:

```vb
Dim XmldocDel As New XmlDocument()
        XmldocDel.Load("" & buildSettingsPath)
        Dim node As XmlNode
        node = XmldocDel.SelectSingleNode("//DataPaths/TableData[ID = '10']")

        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete:", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            If node IsNot Nothing Then
            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)
            'node.ParentNode.RemoveAll()

            XmldocDel.Save("" & buildSettingsPath)
            Reload()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No node found")
        End If

        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

I'm getting a null Exception here.

Solution 2:

```vb
Dim clientNodes = XmldocDel.SelectNodes("//ID")
        For Each elem As Xml.XmlElement In clientNodes
            If elem.InnerText = "10" Then
                elem.ParentNode.RemoveChild(elem)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

This will simply do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using solution 1, since you want to delete the whole `TableData` element, the XPath should've selected `TableData` element instead of `ID` element :

```
.....
node = XmldocDel.SelectSingleNode("//DataPaths/TableData[ID = '10']")
.....
```

*) updated above XPath a bit. Looking at the XML posted, the first step should be `DataPaths` instead of `DataSetPaths`.

**UPDATE :**

Your actual XML has default namespace. So in this case, you need to register a prefix mapped to the default namespace URI using `XmlNamespaceManager`. Use the registered prefix in the XPath, and pass the namespace manager as 2nd parameter of `SelectSingleNode()`
method :

```
Dim nsManager As New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable())
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://tempuri.org/DataPaths.xsd")
.....
node = XmldocDel.SelectSingleNode("//d:DataPaths/d:TableData[d:ID = '10']", nsManager)
.....
```

**[[.NET fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bZlEoE)]**

Comment: @TomWayne This code will certainly not result in a null exception. Your unchecked use of `node` one line later however would. Your fault, never use variables that can be `null` without checking if they are valid.

Comment: Was a pasting mistake by myself (the path should be correct) see updated question.
Now it gives me the MessageBox "No node found"

Comment: @TomWayne Your actual XML must have significant difference from the one posted here (I suspect it has default namespace?). The code should work against XML posted here, see the demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZTvcIT

Comment: `xmlns="tempuri.org/DataPaths.xsd"` is the default namespace. check updated answer for one possible solution

Comment: updated comment:
@har07 I also think so....even this code will select nothing:
'node = XmldocDel.SelectSingleNode("/DataPaths/TableData[1]/ID")'

the xml begins with:
'<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataPaths xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataPaths.xsd">'

I also have to admit that I am completly new to VB and working with XML Data. I never understood why the namespace only works with that content.
Do I even have to use the namespace?

Comment: it works!! I only had to add "http://" (I updated your answer)
Thank you sooo much!
The last thing that I'd like to know: I don't get the xml working without using the namespace. Is it really necessary? All other solutions that I found had no namespaces